Microsoft.Office.Interop is showing login dialog for a file but not for others
I've developed an application that utilizes Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to access .docx files and convert them into .txt format. The application functions smoothly with most .docx files, except for one particular document. Whenever the application attempts to open this specific .docx file, it consistently prompts a login screen. Notably, this file isn't password protected, and I can open it directly using Word without encountering any issues. I must either dismiss the credentials dialog to proceed with the request or supply the correct credentials. However, the next time the problematic file is processed, the same dialog reappears. I'm confused as to why this particular file triggers the login screen while others do not. I have tried to fix the issue with both the Open and OpenNoRepairDialog methods as shown in the following code sample:
 Application app = new Application
 {
     DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone
 };
 WdSaveFormat saveFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatText;

 string sourceFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "oddFile.docx");
 var targetFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "oddFile.txt");

 try
 { 
     //app.Documents.Open(sourceFilePath, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

     app.Documents.OpenNoRepairDialog(sourceFile, false, false, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
         Type.Missing, WdOpenFormat.wdOpenFormatAuto, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, false);

     app.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(targetFile, saveFormat);
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {

 }
 finally
 {         
     app.ActiveDocument.Close();
     app.Quit();
     app = null;
 }

The dialog that appears when opening the odd file in the c# code:


Is there anything in the document that references an external resource such as OneDrive  or Sharepoint?

@phuzi There aren't any external resources which need authentication. There are a few webpage links but they don't require authentication.
